# The target "RunResolvePublishAssemblies" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I'm working on a WPF application, using VS 2017 version 15.3.3

I was curious to know what's behind the file type Azure Function:
When I added it there was nothing changed in the solution explorer, I ignored that and continued my work (which has nothing to do with Azure), but when I compiled the project I get this error:

> The target "RunResolvePublishAssemblies" does not exist in the project

and this warning:

> Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features,
>   such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects
>   that depend on it, have been disabled

I switched the solution explorer to view all files, and I found the azure function class is hidden in the place I added in, I deleted it, but the same problem still exist

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was happening because we switched Azure functions project back from dot net core to 4.5.1. So i deleted 'bin' and 'obj' folders from each of the projects, and re-build. It started working fine for me once deleting these 2 folders. I was able to clean and build the projects. My unit tests are also passing fine.

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub error log helped me with this error: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/92

Following this suggestion resolved my build error:

> To work-around this specific issue , you may be able to give an empty target in your csproj
>   `<Target Name="RunResolvePublishAssemblies" />` but I am not sure what else would be broken without using the SDK style projects.